# Display SWF file in HTML page on the fly using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

so basically what I need to do is display an swf maybe 10 seconds after someone presses a button. I currently have the SWF in my code and it is hidden on page load using the jquery hide function. I am then using the settimeout function to time the jquery show function to show the SWF 10 seconds after the button is pressed. This is VERY buggy. Some days it works, some days it doesnt, literally. A month ago it would kind of half show up on my screen, now it doesn't show up at all. Its different on every browser/computer. Is there a bettter, different way, to do this? I have spent A LOT of tiem trying to make it work using this method. Sorry for any typos, in a rush.

Comment: Post the problematic code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use the `<object>` tag: *([reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp))*

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/TEttF/)

HTML:

```
<object data="file.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="[your swf's width]" height="[your swf's height]" style="display:none;" id="SWF">
    <param name="movie" value="file.swf">

    <!-- If flash is not installed -->
    <p>You need Adobe Flash Player to view this content</p>
</object>

<input type="button" value="Show .swf" id="showSWFButton">
```

JS:

```
$('#showSWFButton').click(function(){
    setTimeout(showSWF,10000) //10 000 milliseconds = 10 seconds
})

function showSWF(){
    $('#SWF').show();
}
```